# CakePHP 2.x form helper date not showing

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I try to use the CakePHP Form Helper to create a DMY select:

```
echo $this->Form->create('ReportCleaner');
echo $this->Form->input('repday', array('dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'minYear' => date('Y'),
                                             'maxYear' => date('Y') + 1, 'label' => 'Date','value'=>'1987-02-12','empty'=>false));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

But it's showing me only a simple input field.

**UPDATE AFTER PROBLEM SOLVED:**

```
echo $this->Form->input('repday', array('dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'minYear' => date('Y'),
                                             'maxYear' => date('Y') + 1, 'label' => 'Date','empty'=>false, 'type'=>'date'));
```

Problem was that this field was coming from different model and not recognized as date. the type option fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `type="date"` if your field is not detected or set as one in the model

Comment: where i have to place this option? the field is coming from different model.

Comment: in that case you can probably use "OtherModel.repday" and please mark my answer ;)

Comment: i tried the "CleanerReport.repday" but didn't worked... but the type thing works fine so i'm okay